# Не получается создать подменю в андроид

Tags: android, разметка

Моей целью было создать меню, похожее на меню в QuickEdit. Для наглядности скриншоты:
[image: меню приложения]

[image: поведение при нажатии на элемент меню, который мне нужен]

То-есть мне необходимо отображать подменю, при нажатии на элемент основного меню. Я это и пытался реализовать. Вот разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- main group -->
    <group
        android:id="@+id/menu_main_group"
        android:visible="true">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/search_menu_item"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:title="@string/search"
            app:showAsAction="always" />

        <item android:title="Save"
            android:id="@+id/file_menu_item"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_file_save_button"
                    android:title="@string/save" >
                </item>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_file_save_as_button"
                    android:title="@string/saveAs" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_file_open_button"
                    android:title="@string/open" />
            </menu>
        </item>

    </group>
    <!-- search group -->
    <group
        android:id="@+id/menu_search_group"
        android:visible="false">
        <item android:title=""
            android:id="@+id/menu_search_prev_button"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
            android:iconTint="@color/black"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/menu_search_next_button"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
            android:iconTint="@color/black"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Но данная разметка не дает ожидаемый результат. При нажатии на **file_menu_item** не происходит совершенно ничего. Я прошерстил несколько руководств по созданию подменю и смотрел видео на эту тему. Ни в одном из примеров не было какого-то кода, для отображения подменю при клике на элемент меню. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Меню реализуется в три шага.

1. Создайте разметку R.menu.menu_main в пакете res/menu
2. Переопределите метод создания и передайте ему свою разметку

```kotlin
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    val inflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

3. Переопределите метод, слушателя нажати, где `item.itemId` ваши `android:id` из разметки.

```kotlin
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_name -> {
            // выполните нужное действие, открытие экрана и т.д.
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Сообщите если вы используете java или создаете меню во фрагменте, ответ нужно будет редактировать

Для реализации подменю, нужно создать еще одну разметку sub_menu.xml, для пунктов подменю, например:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:title="SubMenu One"
    android:id="@+id/submenu_one" />
  <item android:title="SubMenu Two"
    android:id="@+id/submenu_two" />
  <item android:title="SubMenu Three"
    android:id="@+id/submenu_three" />
</menu>
```

Отредактируйте ваш main_menu.xml:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:title="My Menu"
    android:id="@+id/my_menu_item">
    <!-- мы оставляем item пустым, но с типом menu -->
    <menu></menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Отредактируйте метод создания меню:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // раздуваем main меню
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)

        // находим item который содержит sub_menu
        val myMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.my_menu_item)

        // раздуваем sub_menu таким образом
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.sub_menu, myMenuItem.subMenu)
        return true
    }
```

Ваша реализация
main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_menu_item"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:title="Save"
        android:id="@+id/file_menu_item"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save">
        <menu></menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

file_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_file_save_button"
        android:title="menu_file_save_button" >
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_file_save_as_button"
        android:title="menu_file_save_as_button" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_file_open_button"
        android:title="menu_file_open_button" />
</menu>
```

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        val fileMenuItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.file_menu_item)
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.file_menu, fileMenuItem?.subMenu)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: разметка menu_main присутствует, её я и вложил в вопрос. Методы `onCreateOptionsMenu` и `onOptionsItemSelected` реализованы. Тут возникает вопрос, как мне вызвать подменю при клике на элемент меню программно, если это требуется

Comment: @Pavel внимательно прочитал вопрос, все увидел, ожидайте

Comment: @Pavel проверьте обновленный ответ

Comment: благодарю за помощь

Comment: по данному вами примеру, я изменил код следующим образом:
`override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)

        val fileMenuItem = menu!!.findItem(R.id.file_menu_item)
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.file_menu, fileMenuItem!!.subMenu)

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }`

и на строке `menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.file_menu, fileMenuItem!!.subMenu)`

возникает ошибка `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: вот более подробный текст ошибки:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.add(int, int, int, java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @Pavel не смогло найти fileMenuItem, убедитесь что вы используете правильный id. R.id.file_menu_item должен быть элементом R.menu.main_menu В который вы как бы раздуваете ваше R.menu.file_menu . Еще раз, первая строка, раздувает ваше main_menu, вам в этом меню нужно найти элемент, с типом <menu> (в моем примере это android:id="@+id/my_menu_item"), что бы в него надуть R.menu.file_menu (третья строка)

Comment: элемент с таким id точно есть в моем меню. Вот он:

`<item android:title="Save"
            android:id="@+id/file_menu_item"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save">
            <menu />
        </item>`

Comment: @Pavel прикрепите пожалуйста к вопросу ваши обе xml в полном виде. А так же реализации двух методов.

Comment: `main_menu.xml` -> https://pastebin.com/0Ax6HGDX 
`file_menu.xml` -> https://pastebin.com/tbZcpxhf
`реализация методов` -> https://pastebin.com/4emyuH0a

Comment: @Pavel проблема в атрибуте </group>, без него в main_menu все отлично работает, прикрепляю к ответу готовую реализацию под ваш код

Comment: @Pavel буду благодарен за лайк ответа

Comment: Но группы меню я использовал для изменения видимого содержания меню, путём изменения параметра visibility. А как мне это делать без групп?

Comment: @Pavel menu.getItem(i).setVisible(false);

Comment: Благодарю за помощь ʘ‿ʘ

Comment: @Pavel спасибо за хороший вопрос, с вас лайк (͡ᵔ ͜ʖ ͡ᵔ)

Comment: лайк поставил;)